# SQL Server 2000 - Bulk insert from dataset/or C# collection

Tags: c#, sql-server-2000

I know SQL Server 2000 has a [bulk insert.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa225968%28v=sql.80%29.aspx)  Does it support bulk insert from a C# collection, such as a dataset?

I need to insert 30 rows at a time, fairly regularly. I don't want to create 30 DB connections for this if I don't have to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at [SqlBulkCopy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy.aspx) (has according to forums SQL 2000 support). It's easy to use. Basically just provide it with a data table (or data reader) and it will copy the rows from that source to your destination table.

Answer (score 0):

You can insert using a DataSet in SQL 2000, I've never tried because I never use DataSets.

http://www.dotnet247.com/247reference/msgs/3/16570.aspx has a good post on it:

(From the article)

> Steps involved
> 1.Create SqlDataAdapter with proper select statement
>
> 2.Create dataset and fill dataset with SqlDataAdapter
>
> 3.Add rows to the table in the dataset (for all the actions you said above, like radio
> button selected, check box enabled)
>
> 4.Use SqlCommandBuilder helper object to generate the
> UpdateStatements. Its very easy to use command builder. Just a one
> call to the SqlCommandBuilder constructor.
>
> 5.Once your are done adding rows to the datatable int the dataset call
> SqlDataAdapter.update and pass the modified dataset as a parameter.
> This should automatically add the rows from dataset to the
> database.(if no database error occurs)

Have you considered XML?

Working with XML in SQL 2000 isn't as nice as in 2008, but it is still doable:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/insxmldatasqlsvr.aspx

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/generic_OpenXml.aspx

http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;315968

Another option you could look at would be to:

> Open Connection.
> Iterate through the inserts
>
> Close Connection.